# Django - form_valid() vs save()

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

In django forms, for saving other data I usually use `form_valid()` but as I can also use `save()` method of formclass.

Today I overrided `save()` instead of `form_valid()` and I got problem with my manytomanyfield.

When using , the values of manytomanyfield are not saved but when I use `form_valid()` they start saving. Can anybody tell me the reason and what are the differences between both, which is the most convenient method and in what situation?

Here is my overriding of save() method:

```
class ProductCreateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    sizes = make_ajax_field(ProductCreateModel,'sizes','sizes')
    colours = make_ajax_field(ProductCreateModel,'colours','colours')

    class Meta:
        model = ProductCreateModel

        fields = ('title','category',
                    'regions',)

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.request = kwargs.pop("request")
        super(ProductCreateForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self):
        product = super(ProductCreateForm, self).save(commit=False)
        user =  self.request.user

        product.location = user.user_location
        product.save()
        return product
```

When I override form_valid() method:

```
   def get_form_kwargs(self):
       kwargs = super(ProductCreateView,self).get_form_kwargs()
       kwargs.update({'request':self.request})
       return kwargs

   def form_valid(self, form):
       product = form.save(commit=False)
       user =  self.request.user
       form.instance.user = user
       form.instance.location = user.user_location
       form.save()
       return super(ProductCreateView, self).form_valid(form)
```

`sizes`,`colours` and `regions` are m2m fields, as I mentioned when I overrides `save()` values of m2m not get saved but when I overrides `form_valid` they start saving.

Comment: Could you please post your override. Also, could you please explain what do you mean by _they start saving_. You see them in the database ? They appear on your form ?

Comment: @scharette I added my both methods.

Answer (score 11):

If you save a form with `commit=False`, you must call the form's `save_m2m` method to save the many-to-many data. See [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method) for more info.

If you decide to use the `form_valid` method, I would change the following things:

- update the instance returned by `form.save()` and save it, instead of calling `form.save()` again.
- explicitly call `form.save_m2m()`
- return a redirect response instead of calling `super().form_valid()` (which will save the form again)

Putting that together, you get:

```
def form_valid(self, form):
    product = form.save(commit=False)
    product.user =  self.request.user
    product.location.location = user.user_location
    product.save()
    form.save_m2m()
    return redirect('/success-url/')
```

Comment: Will also add that recommending  `redirect` should be based on choice since the generic `view.form_valid` already returns a `HttpResponseRedirect` to the success_url.

Comment: @jackotonye I already explained why I recommend returning a redirect response - if you call `super().form_valid()` then the form is saved again. There are alternative approaches (e.g. response = super(ProductCreateView, self).form_valid(form); form.save_m2m; return response` but I prefer the explicit return.

Answer (score 1):

About your problem with manytomany i guess is the order they do things... Form > Admin > Models, when you use form_valid is the first thing they do before check other things in chain, while using save is the last, maybe can be because or other things too...

The best way is always use form_valid instead of raw save

**form_valid** first check the Clean function if there is any native validations errors or custom validations and only then save your models

**save** just save it without validate then with your form with your validations

Example

```
from django import forms

class ContactForm(forms.Form):
    # Everything as before.
    ...

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        cc_myself = cleaned_data.get("cc_myself")
        subject = cleaned_data.get("subject")

        if cc_myself and subject:
            # Only do something if both fields are valid so far.
            if "help" not in subject:
                raise forms.ValidationError(
                    "Did not send for 'help' in the subject despite "
                    "CC'ing yourself."
                )
```

Source: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/forms/validation/

Comment: thanks for the answer but please don't say `form_valid` is first, When I write print statement in both methods, print statement of `save()` executed first and then `form_valid`, please edit your answer and don't write guesses.

Comment: You know that inside form_valid he can call saves... but if you place commit=false the save wont be called and you will call it manually... so yes form_valid is called first and save inside him after it. so im not guessing

Comment: Like i said... first check if is valid, inside it runs Clean and then Saves

Comment: ok, you are right, as I am printing after super in `form_valid` save() method executed in super and print statement of save printed first.