# How does form_valid work in django? How does it compare to save()?

Tags: django

**The describtion of this in docs seems very sparse and unclear to me I am asking here. So what is exactly doing the form_valid method here? From what I understand, it gets triggered with POST method and it is kinda calling save() in the last line.
form.instance.entry_author=self.request.user in this line I understand that we are setting the current user to be the author but I dont understand why form referances to instance and also where did the form get from? I suppose its in-built in the form-valid function?**

```
class CreateEntryView(CreateView):
        model = Entry
        template_name='entries/create_entry.html'
        fields = ['entry_title','entry_text']
    
        def form_valid(self, form):
            form.instance.entry_author=self.request.user
            return super().form_valid(form)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Django - form\_valid() vs save()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51172820/django-form-valid-vs-save)

Comment: https://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/3.0/django.views.generic.edit/CreateView/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CreateView` is a generic view which does a few things for you automatically without you having to write the logic yourself. One of those things is creating a Form. You indicated the model to use, which is `Entry`. Based on the `fields`, `CreateView` creates a form and uses that form.

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/class-based-views/mixins-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.ModelFormMixin.form_valid): `form_valid` saves the form instance, sets the current object for the view, and redirects to get_success_url().

You can override this if you have any special requirements. Notice that `entry_author` is not included in the `fields` so it will not be present in the form. The idea here is to set the entry_author automatically instead of the user choosing the author in the form.

Comment: yeah great thanks!but why the form a making a reference to entry_author if entry_author isnt present in the form?

Comment: It is intentional. If it was in the form, the user would have to choose the author. The logic here is the user SHOULD NOT be able to choose the author. Instead, it should be set automatically.